# TensorFlow: why not use a function instead of a placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am starting to use TensorFlow (with Python) and was wondering: when using a placeholder in a function, why not have an argument in my function  which would feed a TensorFlow constant rather than the placeholder?

Here is an example (the difference is in `x`):

```
def sigmoid(z):
    x = tf.constant(z, dtype=tf.float32, name = "x")
    sigmoid = tf.sigmoid(x)
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        result = sess.run(sigmoid)
    return result
```

instead of:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = "...")
    sigmoid = tf.sigmoid(x)
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        result = sess.run(sigmoid, feed_dict={x:z})
    return result
```

Comment: Neither one of these things is a typical tensorflow use case

Answer (score 3):

The idea with Tensorflow is that you will repeat the same calculation on lots of data. when you write the code you are setting up a computational graph that later you will execute on the data. In your first example, you have hard-coded the data to a constant. This is not a typical tensorflow use case. The second example is better because it allows you to reuse the same computational graph with different data.

Comment: Also using a placeholder is better for the computation time, when utilizing a GPU. Thus, memory required can get preallocated and not just when it gets needed in the function